# How to call a instance method from a CharField in Django

Tags: django, django-1.9

My code is as follows...

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    state_choice = (('To Do','To Do'),('Doing','Doing'),('Done','Done'))

    def get_color_depends_state(self):
      if self.state:
         if self.state == 'To Do':
             self.color_code = '87CEEB'
         elif self.state == 'Doing':
            self.color_code = '7D3C98'
         elif self.state == 'Done':
            self.color_code = '00FF7F'  


    state = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=state_choice,default='todo')

    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=self.get_color_depends_state)
```

My field color_code depends on the values of state field. I am trying to call the function from the color_code field but it is giving errors like *self not defined* or *module has no attribute get_color_depends_state*.

How I can call an instance method from field which intern depends on other field values(*Here state*)

Comment: Your ``default='todo'`` in the state so wouldn't it make sense to default color_code to ``'87CEEB'``, which is the default for todo?. Also, I think your ``deafult = 'todo'`` should be changed to ``default='TO DO'``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in the default attribute, and it doesn't make sense to do so anyway as that is applied when the model is instantiated - so all the other fields would be blank as well.

Instead you should override the `save` method and do this logic there, checking that the field is blank and setting it to the default if so.

Comment: Thanks. One more doubt, Is it possible to call an instance method from a field

Comment: I don't understand that question, I'm afraid.

Comment: how to call an instance function from the default attribute of a field. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
  state_choice = (('To Do', 'To Do'), ('Doing', 'Doing'), ('Done', 'Done'))

  state = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=state_choice, default='todo')

  color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

  def get_color_depends_state(self):
     if self.state:
        if self.state == 'To Do':
           self.color_code = '87CEEB'
        elif self.state == 'Doing':
           self.color_code = '7D3C98'
        elif self.state == 'Done':
           self.color_code = '00FF7F'

  def save(self, *args):
    self.get_color_depends_state()
    super(Todo, self).save(*args)
```